# How to use const in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I added a `const` but I am not able to access it in styles
[image]

[image]

It is giving the error not able to find the variable size

```
import React, {  useState } from 'react'; //import useState
    import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput,StatusBar, SafeAreaView,Image,Button,Alert} from 'react-native';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
    
    
    export default function App() {
        const [size, setSize] = useState('95%')
        const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); //add this line
        
      return (      
        
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
              onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
              onFocus={()=>setSize(1)}
              placeholder="Search"
              style={styles.searchbox}     
                                 
            ></TextInput>   
    
          <View style={styles.makecentral} >   
            {search.length < 1 ? <Image               
                style={styles.tinyLogo}
                source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')}        
              /> : ( 
                  null  //add clear text image and clear search text
                  
              )}
          
          </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    
                  <View elevation={2}  style={{flex:3,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',height:40,marginTop:10,marginLeft:'2.5%',borderBottomLeftRadius:5,borderTopLeftRadius:5}}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:20,color:'#FF7B00',marginTop:7}}>
                      Category
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  
                  <View elevation={2} style={{backgroundColor:'#FF7B00',height:40,flex:5,marginTop:10,borderTopRightRadius:5,borderBottomRightRadius:5,marginRight:'2.5%'}}>
         
                  <DropDownPicker
                      items={[
                          {label: 'USA', value: 'usa', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />, hidden: true},
                          {label: 'UK', value: 'uk', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
                          {label: 'France', value: 'france', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />},
                      ]}
                      
                      containerStyle={{height: 40}}
                      style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
                      
                   
                    />
    
                  </View>
                 
                
                </View>
    
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {    
        backgroundColor: '#fff',    
        
      },
    
      searchbox:{
        backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
        marginTop : StatusBar.currentHeight+5,
        height : 50,
        width : '95%',
        borderRadius : 20,
        textAlignVertical:'center',
        textAlign : 'center',
        alignItems:'center',        
      },
    
      tinyLogo: {
        position : 'absolute',
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        
        opacity: 0.5,
        marginTop: -40,    
      },
    
      makecentral: {
        
        alignItems:'center',
        marginRight:80,    
      },
    
      category:{
        backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',
        height:50,
        width:'90%',
        alignContent:'center',
    
    
      }
    })

;
```

Comment: Give us a full snippet of your code. i think your `searchbox` object is placed in a wrong area and does not have access to states.

Comment: added please check.

Comment: Yes. as i said, you need to move object inside your function. as an another way you can use @SilverskyTechnology answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are supposed to use the dynamic style in your component or views then you have to put it as inline style like the below example:

```
<MyComponent style={{ ...styles.searchbox, width: MY_DYNAMIC_SIZE }}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, your `size` is used before it is defined. You have to use it as `in-line style`: `<Component className={classes.searchbox} style={{width: size}} />`.

Comment: but we should avoid inline styling .

Comment: It's nothing wrong with inline styling. It might not be so cool looking like when you declare your style for classes, but it's helpful, especially when you need some conditioning styling

Answer (score 1):

Create a method and pass parameters which are required and return the stylesheet. Please refer below code

```
export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState('95%');
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); //add this line
 const styles = getStyles(size);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
          onFocus={() => setSize(1)}
          placeholder="Search"
          style={styles.searchbox}
        ></TextInput>

        <View style={styles.makecentral}>
          {
            search.length < 1 ? (
              <Image style={styles.tinyLogo} source={require('./assets/icons8_search_200px_3.png')} />
            ) : null //add clear text image and clear search text
          }
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View
            elevation={2}
            style={{
              flex: 3,
              backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
              height: 40,
              marginTop: 10,
              marginLeft: '2.5%',
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, color: '#FF7B00', marginTop: 7 }}>
              Category
            </Text>
          </View>

          <View
            elevation={2}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FF7B00',
              height: 40,
              flex: 5,
              marginTop: 10,
              borderTopRightRadius: 5,
              borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
              marginRight: '2.5%',
            }}
          >
            <DropDownPicker
              items={[
                {
                  label: 'USA',
                  value: 'usa',
                  icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />,
                  hidden: true,
                },
                { label: 'UK', value: 'uk', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
                { label: 'France', value: 'france', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
              ]}
              containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
              style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const getStyles = (size) => {
  return StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },

    searchbox: {
      backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
      marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight + 5,
      height: 50,
      width: size,
      borderRadius: 20,
      textAlignVertical: 'center',
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },

    tinyLogo: {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: 30,
      height: 30,

      opacity: 0.5,
      marginTop: -40,
    },

    makecentral: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginRight: 80,
    },

    category: {
      backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
      height: 50,
      width: '90%',
      alignContent: 'center',
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

"styles" is outside your function. Put it inside and it will work.